# Can any body please direct me to Step by Step guide to setup example website of DXA 1.3 JAVA using SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 in eclipse

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-java

Can any body please direct me to Step by Step guide to setup example website of DXA 1.3 JAVA using SDL Tridion 2013 sp1 in eclipse. I have tried referring to following blogs.

https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/15/getting-started-with-dxa-java

https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/15/getting-started-with-dxa-java

Both these blogs are referring to paths which are no longer valid for DXA 1.3 download of JAVA. For example "DXA.Java 1.2 distribution: web/tridion-libs/7.1.0" this path no longer exists in the DXA 1.3 repository.

Please suggest how can I proceed forward to setup the example website in eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say follow the similar setup that is mentioned for dxa 1.2 java  -

(https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/getting-started-with-dxa-java)

for DXA 1.3 you would-

- Get Related jars that could be added to lib of webapp from-
  `(\Download Dir\web\install\source-war\2013sp1\WEB-INF\lib)`
- Get the DXA source code from Github & compile/install it your local Maven repository

  WebApp+Framework - `https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java`

  Modules- `https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules`
- Create a DXA web application/Use example webapp using correct configurations

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check this official documentation link http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-2DEBAC0B-C053-4221-B7B9-9966D03A25B1

Comment: Thanks for your response but this tutorial is for deployment of application i.e. creating a war file. I need steps to setup the example website in eclipse. Which I can use as development/playground project.